# Changing multiple elements (of known coordinates) of a matrix without a for loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a matrix say

```
Z = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9]
```

I have to change its values, say at positions (2,2) and (3,1), to some specified value. I have two matrices `rowNos` and `colNos` which contain these positions:

```
rowNos = [2, 3]
colNos = [2, 1]
```

Let's say I want to change the value of elements at these positions to 0.

How can I do it without using for loop?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a loop here?

Comment: @MarcusRiemer, Because I am going to apply this thing on large images. Huge ones in fact. And I feel, Vectorization will help my code run a lot faster than plain for loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html), it'll convert your sub-indices to linear indices, which is a number pointing at one exact spot in the matrix ([more info](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)).

```
Z = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9];
rowNos = [2, 3];
colNos = [2, 1];

lin_idcs = sub2ind(size(Z), rowNos, colNos)
```

If you want to operate on all elements on a specific row and column (elements in higher dimensions that is), you can also address them using linear indexing. It only becomes a bit trickier of calculating them:

```
Z = reshape(1:4*4*3,[4 4 3]);
rowNos = [2, 3];
colNos = [2, 1];

siz = size(Z);
lin_idcs = sub2ind(siz, rowNos, colNos,ones(size(rowNos))); % just the first element of the remaining dimensions
lin_idcs_all = bsxfun(@plus,lin_idcs',prod(siz(1:2))*(0:prod(siz(3:end))-1)); % all of them
lin_idcs_all = lin_idcs_all(:);

Z(lin_idcs_all) = 0;
```

experiment a bit with sub2ind, and go through my code step-by-step to understand it.

It would've been easier if it was the first dimension you wanted to take all elements off, then you could have used the colon operator `:`

```
Z = reshape(1:3*4*4,[3 4 4]);
rowNos = [2, 3];
colNos = [2, 1];

siz = size(Z);
lin_idcs = sub2ind(siz(2:end),rowNos,colNos);
Z(:,lin_idcs) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gunther Struyf . One more small question. How do I extend it to 3-D matrix? What if Z was say 3x3x3 matrix. (I actually want to change RGB values of an image, so I have simplified it this way) So how there are 3 values associated with each position and I want to change them all with 3 other specified values. How do I do that?

Comment: @Shahensha see edit^^ (you should've added that remark in your original question in the first place imho)

Answer (score 2):

Use `sub2ind` with multiple entries for rows and columns

```
Z(sub2ind(size(Z), rowNos, colNos))=0
```

**Example**:

```
Z = [1 2 3;
    4 5 6;
    7 8 9];

rowNos = [2, 3];
colNos = [2, 1];

Z(sub2ind(size(Z), rowNos, colNos))=0

Z =

     1     2     3
     4     0     6
     0     8     9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @gevang.
One more small question. How do I extend it to 3-D matrix? What if Z was say 3x3x3 matrix.
(I actually want to change RGB values of an image, so I have simplified it this way)
So how there are 3 values associated with each position and I want to change them all with 3 other specified values. How do I do that?

Comment: along the same lines with @Gunther Struyf, I would also suggest for 3-dim matrices (i.e. RGB-images) looping across the 3rd dimension, which is clean and not costy (even for huge 2d dimensions), i.e. `c = [-1; -2; -3]; for i=1:3, Z(sub2ind(size(Z), rowNos, colNos, repmat(i, 1, size(rowNos,2)))) = c(i); end`

Answer (score 1):

You would like to do this

```
z(rowNos, colNos)
```

but you can not - MATLAB does a Cartesian product of the indices. You can do this trick

```
idx=(colNos-1)*size(z, 1)+rowNos;
z(idx)=0
```

Flatten the z-matrix and access it through a linear index, which is a combination of rowNos and colNos. Remember that MATLAB flattens the matrix by columns (column-based matrix storage).

Comment: which is essentially what `sub2ind` does, but this works only for 2d matrices (does the trick here of course, but for continuity it's easier to just use sub2ind)

Comment: For higher dimensions you can do the same trick, which is not really a trick but exactly what sub2ind does. But its true that this requires knowledge of MATLABs data structure. sub2ind frees you from that, but I like to know exactly how things work.

Comment: (nofi) so you also calculate the mean of a vector using `sum(x)/length(x)` :p

Comment: well. I more often than not write mex files, so in a sense - yes :p I mostly had in mind the data structures, and how they work in MATLAB.