# Selecting elements from an array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I know that in MATLAB, in the 1D case, you can select elements with indexing such as `a([1 5 3])`, to return the 1st, 5th, and 3rd elements of a. I have a 2D array, and would like to select out individual elements according to a set of tuples I have. So I may want to get `a(1,3), a(1,4), a(2,5)` and so on. Currently the best I have is `diag(a(tuples(:,1), tuples(:,2))`, but this requires a prohibitive amount of memory for larger a and/or tuples. Do I have to convert these tuples into linear indices, or is there a cleaner way of accomplishing what I want without taking so much memory?

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146082/indexing-of-unknown-dimensional-matrix, as it covers the same problem you have

Comment: Or you could look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294232/changing-multiple-elements-of-known-coordinates-of-a-matrix-without-a-for-loop/12294606#12294606) to see essentially the same answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing them out; I searched and only found cases of logical indexing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting to linear indices seems like a legitimate way to go:

```
indices = tuples(:, 1) + size(a,1)*(tuples(:,2)-1);
selection = a(indices);
```

Note that this is also implement in the Matlab built-in solution `sub2ind`, as in nate'2 answer:

```
a(sub2ind(size(a), tuples(:,1),tuples(:,2)))
```

however,

```
a = rand(50);
tuples = [1,1; 1,4; 2,5];

start = tic;
for ii = 1:1e4
    indices = tuples(:,1) + size(a,1)*(tuples(:,2)-1); end
time1 = toc(start);


start = tic;
for ii = 1:1e4
    sub2ind(size(a),tuples(:,1),tuples(:,2)); end
time2 = toc(start);

round(time2/time1)
```

which gives

```
ans =   
    38
```

so although `sub2ind` is easier on the eyes, it's also ~40 times *slower*. If you have to do this operation often, choose the method above. Otherwise, use `sub2ind` to improve readability.

Comment: NOTE: Matlab is 1-based, so you'll have to use `m*(tuples(:,2)-1)`. Otherwise, this solution is some ~40 times faster than `sub2ind`, so it has my preference :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I would also prefer this one. However, [I previously got mildly criticized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294232/changing-multiple-elements-of-known-coordinates-of-a-matrix-without-a-for-loop/12294606#12294606) on SO for that, and `sub2ind` was the way to go. Interesting how people change their mind in what they like :)

Comment: @angainor: Ah well, there are as many opinions as there are people. I just wonder what the heck `sub2ind` does to make it consume so much time...You know, we should start a new toolbox, something like [lightspeed](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/), especially for things like this :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis You know how the story goes: "... MATLAB has to take care of the general cases, and your case is special, so of course MATLAB can be slower ...". But it is much more general ;)

Answer (score 3):

if x and y are vectors of the x y values of matrix a, then sub2und should solve your problem:

```
a(sub2ind(size(a),x,y))
```

For example

> a=magic(3)
>
> a =
>
> ```
>  8     1     6
>  3     5     7
>  4     9     2
> ```

```
x = [3 1];
y = [1 2];


a(sub2ind(size(a),x,y))

ans =

 4     1
```

Comment: Both methods are good. This one also seamlessly works for higher dimensions, +1. Although for faster execution the other is better.

Answer (score 0):

you can reference the 2D matlab position with a 1D number as in:

```
a = [3 4 5;
     6 7 8;
     9 10 11;];
a(1) = 3;
a(2) = 6;
a(6) = 10;
```

So if you can get the positions in a matrix like this:

```
a([(col1-1)*(rowMax)+row1, (col2-1)*(rowMax)+row2, (col3-1)*(rowMax)+row3])
```

note: rowmax is 3 in this case

will give you a list of the elements at col1/row1 col2/row2 and col3/row3.

so if

```
row1 = col1 = 1
row2 = col2 = 2
row3 = col3 = 3
```

you will get:

```
[3, 7, 11]
```

back.